# Django database model "unique_together" not working?

Tags: mysql, django, model, key, unique

I want my `ip` and `stream_id` combination to be unique, so I wrote this model:

```
# Votes
class Vote(models.Model):
    # The stream that got voted
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream)

    # The IP adress of the voter
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 15)

    vote = models.BooleanField()

    unique_together = (("stream", "ip"),)
```

But for some reason it produces this table, skipping the `ip`

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE website_vote;
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+
| website_vote | CREATE TABLE `website_vote` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stream_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `vote` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `website_vote_7371fd6` (`stream_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why doesn't it include `ip` in the key? For the record I am aware that the `unique_together` line can be written without nesting the tuples, but that has no bearing on the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unique_together` needs to be in the models `Meta` class.  See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together).

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    # The stream that got voted
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream)

    # The IP adress of the voter
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 15)

    vote = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("stream", "ip"),)
```

Also, there's a builtin `IPAddressField` model field.  See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ipaddressfield).